# Toggle UL Contents and Update Text

Tags: jquery, toggle

I have this code which toggle slides the contents of a UL:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
  jQuery("ul.item-options").click(function (evt) {
    if(evt.target.tagName != 'UL')
    return;
    jQuery("li", this).slideToggle(500);
  });
});
```

```css
.item-options li {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class='item-options'>
  show
  <li>list item</li>
</ul>

<ul class='item-options'>
  show
  <li>list item</li>
</ul>

<ul class='item-options'>
  show
  <li>list item</li>
</ul>
```

I would like to update this so that the word 'show' toggles between show/hide.

Any ideas?

Comment: Wrap your `show` text with something like `span` then toggle the text, or move it out form `ul`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below code - 
get html inside UL and then replace the text as per current value and put html back

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery("ul.item-options").click(function (evt) {
            if(evt.target.tagName != 'UL')
                return;
            var html = jQuery(this).html();
            if(html.indexOf('show')>=0) {
               jQuery(this).html(html.replace('show','hide'));
            } else {
               jQuery(this).html(html.replace('hide','show'));
            }
            jQuery("li", this).slideToggle(500);
           
        });
    });
```

```css
.item-options li {
      display: none;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class='item-options'>
   show
   <li>list item</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly note that your HTML is invalid. You cannot have a text node as the child of a `ul`. To fix this you could move the `show` text outside of the `ul` in to its own element. I used a `p` in the example below, but any other will work.

From there you can attach a `click` event handler to that element which calls `slideToggle()` on the relevant `li` elements and then updates the `text()` of the clicked element based on its current setting. Try this:

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $(".toggle").on('click', function() {
    $('ul li').stop().slideToggle(500);
    $(this).text((i, t) => t == 'show' ? 'hide' : 'show');
  });
});
```

```css
.item-options li {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="toggle">show</p>
<ul class="item-options">
  <li>list item</li>
</ul>
```

Also note the use of `stop()` to prevent the slideToggle animation queueing up if the element is clicked quickly in succession.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think this will work.  I have multiple .item-options ul elements (forgot to mention this in the initial question) so doing it this way would result in all of them toggling every time the .toggle paragraph was clicked.

Comment: In that case use `$(this).next('ul').find('li').stop().slideToggle(500);`. In either case your HTML would need to be changed